# Mysql2 connection in ruby always take my Ip address to connect and ignores the value in host

Tags: ruby, database-connection, mysql2

I am trying to connect to my database through mysql2 in ruby with the following:

```
client = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => host, :username => username, :password => password, :database => database)
```

But I see that my host value no matter what I give is replaced by "my local ip address"

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks,
Rv

Comment: What do you mean by that? What error do you get?

Comment: I mean that I provide host value to be "ABCD" but it is always taking 10.X.X.X
Error I get is Access denied for user 'XYZ'@'10.X.X.X' (using password: YES) (Mysql2::Error)

Comment: You're going to see your local address in the error there since that's where you're connecting *from*.